# JPQL exclude subclasses in a query

Tags: jpa, jpql

If I have a class Apple that extends Fruit, how do I write a JPQL query to return all objects that are strictly Fruits and not Apples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in JPA 2.0 using the `TYPE` operator. From the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 4.6.17.4 Entity Type Expressions
>
> An entity type expression can be used
>   to restrict query polymorphism. The
>   TYPE operator returns the exact type
>   of the argument.
>
> The syntax of an entity type
>   expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> entity_type_expression ::=
>         type_discriminator |
>         entity_type_literal |
>         input_parameter
> type_discriminator ::=
>         TYPE(identification_variable |
>              single_valued_object_path_expression |
>              input_parameter )
> ```
>
> An *entity_type_literal* is
>   designated by the entity name.
>
> The Java class of the entity is used
>   as an input parameter to specify the
>   entity type.

So you could do something like this:

```
SELECT f
FROM Fruit f
WHERE TYPE(f) <> Apple
```

But this is not available in JPA 1.0 and if you are using JPA 1.0, you'd have to rely on a provider specific extension (please mention your provider in that case).

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 4.4.8 "Polymorphism"
  - Section 4.6.17.4 "Entity Type Expressions"

Comment: Please add a link to the original source because it's impossible to understand `<>` intuitively.